# write and printf out of order output

Tags: c, printf, output, order-of-execution

While writing a c program I encountered a puzzling behavior with printf and write. It appears that write is in some cases called before printf even though it is after it in the code (is printf asynchronous?). Also if there are two lines in the printf, output after that appears to be inserted between them. My question is what causes this behavior and how can I know what will happen when? What about other output functions (ex. puts) - can I look out for something in the documentation to know how they will behave with others. Example code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "1.", 2);
    printf("2.");
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "3.", 2);
    printf("4.\n5.");
    printf("6.");
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "7.", 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1.3.2.4.
7.5.6.
```

Comment: Printf is buffered write is not bufferdd

Comment: To be more precise, `stdout` (which is the `FILE *` where `printf` writes) is by default *line* buffered. That means whenever you have a newline in your `printf` output, everything in the buffer, up to and including the newline, is *flushed* and written to the underlying device (which on POSIX systems like Linux is usually `STDOUT_FILENO`).

Comment: To be even more precise, on POSIX-compliant systems (read "practically everything except Windows, these days") `stdout` is line-buffered _if it is connected to a terminal_, fully-buffered otherwise. For instance, the output of this program when run as `./a.out` will be different from its output when run as `./a.out | cat`.

Comment: this is very informative you may add it in the answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`write` is not buffered `printf` is. Whenever you use `write` it gets to the console - but `printf` is outputted when it gets `\n` here, because then the buffer is flushed.

That's why after `1.3.` you see `2.4.`

You can flush the output by using `fflush(stdout)` right after the `printf` calls. (`Steve Summit` commented this)

You may wonder there is no other `\n` after that `printf` so why do those characters are flushed?

On program termination the output buffer is also flushed. That is what causes the rest of the `printf` outputs to appear. <sup>The `setvbuf()` function may only be used after opening a stream and before any other operations have been performed on it.</sup>

---

Also as `zwol` mentioned you can turn of line bufferng of `stdout` using this before making any other call to standard I/O functions.

```
setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IONBF, 0)
                   ^^^
                   causes input/output to be unbuffered
```

Comment: OP can call `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf`s to make sure they interleave properly.  Or, call `fwrite` instead of `write`..

Comment: Or `setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IONBF, 0)` before making any other calls to stdio.h functions.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the mentioned use of `fflush()` after each output operation, you could also make `stdout` *unbuffered* with

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

This way, all output by `printf`, `puts`, `putchar`, ... would appear in order with `write` output (without the need to sprinkle a lot of fflush()s around).